# Faster solution for an R function

Tags: r, gps, distance, heatmap

I am trying to create a "player heat map during a match." something like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xroTU.jpg). I have gps data in a gpx format and have been able to upload the file into R. The data is as follows:

```
         lon      lat  ele                     time position sat
1  20.84293 15.82110 23.9 2016-03-28T17:28:19.407Z        1   3
2  20.84315 15.82129 23.9 2016-03-28T17:28:20.407Z        2   3
3  20.84309 15.82118 23.9 2016-03-28T17:28:22.407Z        3   3
4  20.84269 15.82089 23.9 2016-03-28T17:28:23.407Z        4   3
5  20.84277 15.82092 23.9 2016-03-28T17:28:24.407Z        5   3
6  20.84289 15.82102 23.9 2016-03-28T17:28:25.411Z        6   3
7  20.84306 15.82117 23.9 2016-03-28T17:28:27.411Z        7   3
8  20.84308 15.82115 23.9 2016-03-28T17:28:28.411Z        8   3
9  20.84292 15.82108 23.9 2016-03-28T17:28:29.411Z        9   3
10 20.84307 15.82124 23.9 2016-03-28T17:28:30.412Z       10   3
```

In order to create the heat map. I decided to measure the distance of each point to all the other points in the dataset and count all the distances that are less than 5m, or any number. Then used that information to color code each point. e.g. points with more points within 5m will be red, then orange, yellow, etc..

To measure the distance between all points, I came up with this function:

```
numberClosePoints=function(df,i,radius){
  close_points=c()
  while(i<=nrow(df)){  # looping while i <= the number of rows in the data frame
    j = 1 # ... initializing j
    count = 0 # count of distances for each i
    while(j<=nrow(df)){# looping while j is < 5
      dist=pointDistance(c(geodf$lon[i],geodf$lat[i]), c(geodf$lon[j],geodf$lat[j]),lonlat=T)
      if (dist <= radius | is.nan(dist)){ # Add the is.nan because for some reason the distance between 5 and 5 was NaN and the function stops
        count = count + 1
      }
      j = j + 1   # incrementing j
    }
    close_points <- c(close_points,count-1)
    i = i + 1    # incrementing i
  }
  return(close_points)
}
```

It does work just fine. However, with larger datasets, the time making the calculations is increased. I can wait, after all, there are not that many points from a match ~3600 to 4000 (1 per second for 2 hrs).

I was wondering if there is a way to make this go faster, or have a more efficient way to do either the heat map or the function?

Comment: there's a `dist()` function for comparing points to all other points. Maybe give that a whirl

Comment: You might look into hexbins. Also, there's a basketball version that you might use as inspiration... http://toddwschneider.com/posts/ballr-interactive-nba-shot-charts-with-r-and-shiny/

Comment: Or you could just `with(your_data, graphics::smoothScatter(lon, lat))`.

Comment: or see `help("kde2d",package="MASS")`.  If you gave a reproducible example I bet you'd get some nice solutions.

Comment: The first rule in R to speed up calculations is to avoid loops!  But I think you have larger problem with your logic.  Each row in your data set is a position and if the rows are equal spaced in time, then all you need to do is a create a 2 dimensional histogram.  See ggplot2 its stat_density2d function.  To simplify calculations one could assume planar coordinates since the curve of the earth is insignificant on the scale of a playing field.

Comment: @Dave2e using lat lon is actually important here as 1 degree of longitude is significantly different depending on your latitude

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I did try all of them, I am heading towards Kde2d, as it gives me more options to play with the final graph. I found this site:http://www.r-bloggers.com/5-ways-to-do-2d-histograms-in-r/ that gives examples of all the options you mentioned. Thanks.